# C++11: variadic lambda template for calling the default constructor of a type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, variadic-templates

I want to create a template for a `std::function<T(Variable nums of arguments)>` that returns the default value of a class by calling the default constructor.

I tried this:

```
template <class T,class... Args> inline std::function<T(Args...)> zero(){
    return [](Args...){ return T();};
}
```

I want to use it in occasions where you just need the default value and no complicated function, for instance in my `Image<T>` class:

```
template <typename T> class Image{
    ...
    void drawEachPixel(std::function<T(size_t,size_t)> func){
        forRange(x,w){
            forRange(y,h){
                this->setPixel(x,y,func(x,y));
            }
        }
    }
    ...
};
```

to clear an image I could just call:

```
image.drawEachPixel(zero());
```

when compiling I get the error `no matching function for call to 'Image<unsigned char>::drawEachPixel(std::function<unsigned char()>)'`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just call `zero` without an explicit template argument list. It has template parameters:

```
template <class T, class... Args>
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
inline std::function<T(Args...)> zero()
```

The template arguments cannot be deduced, so the template parameters stay without corresponding types.
Instead, use a conversion operator template:

```
struct Zero
{
     template <typename T, typename... Args>
     operator std::function<T(Args...)> ()
     {
         return [] (Args...) { return T(); };
     }
};
```

And use it as before. [**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc72faaf1c826be6).